# Find First 4 character of the line should be "ORA-" and the next 5 character should be numeric in Unix Command/Script

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

Need to find the words/strings from the file,
   First 4 character of the line should be "ORA-" and the next 5 character should be numeric.

File Name: 1.txt

```
This is test ORA-12345
ORA-01234test
OORA-06550:
ORA-01A34
```

O/P:

```
ORA-01234test
```

Command:

```
egrep "ORA-[0-9]" 1.txt
```

Can not check first 4 should br ORA- and next 5 should be numeric

Comment: `ORA-[0-9]{5}`?

Comment: Have a look at: [**POSIX Basic Regular Expressions**: _BREs Matching Multiple Characters_](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06) and [RegularExpressions.info :: Repeat](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to precise that you want 5 digits (`{5}`) and match from the start of the line with `^`, to avoid matching `OORA-06550:`.

```
egrep "^ORA-[0-9]{5}" 1.txt
```

Comment: Simplified: `^ORA-\d{5}`